# double effect roller bearing or two needle roller bearing

Tags: bearings

Good morning,
I need to source 30 or 50 bearings such as the picture. This is a double effect roller bearing and the mid washer is drilled as you can see.

Shaft diameter: 17mm

Height: 22.26mm

Speed is not an issue

This is not standard and very hard to find.

Instead, I was thinking to put 2 AXK1730 needle bearing + 2*2 AS1730 washers and make another mid washer with the 2 holes

What do you think about this?[image: double effect roller bearing]

Comment: Are the load ratings the same between the different bearings ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything on the current roller bearing so i will test with what i found but 11Kn seems to be more than enough for my purpose